# get Object by key AngularFire

Tags: cordova, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

Im working on a with ionic2,
Now i can get the object as called her down KZ************

But i don't know how to get the object by the key

Firebase database

```
"repairs" : {
"-KZlbEGM6xsqk3-EtP5y" : {
    "chat" : [ ],
    "description" : "desc",
    "status" : 3,
    "titel" : "Wifi",
    "username" : "k7vydyjBBcTbZd7ZoEP0JjXV0qz1"
},
"-KZljUyj_eXwu2k_TcwY" : {
    "chat" : [ ],
    "description" : "desc",
    "status" : 1,
    "titel" : "123",
    "username" : "100033713853174117556"
    }
}
```

Here is my code to get the object

```
this.messages = this.af.database.list('repairs', {
      query: {
        orderByChild: '$key',
        equalTo: this.key
      }
    });
```

Comment: You've included a link to a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access Firebase data when you know the key, just incorporate that key in to the path:

```ts
let key = '-KZljUyj_eXwu2k_TcwY';
this.af.database
  .object(`repairs/${key}`)
  .subscribe((result) => console.log(result));
```

Also, you most likely want to use `object`, rather than `list`.